# Embedding precompiled Angular Offline app into rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails application where one little part has to work offline.
This part can be totally independent, so I chose to let someone else do it outside of the rails stack as an independent angular offline-application that uses the rails application via REST. The angular app will be a precompiled app with a application.manifest file.

Now I want to include it into the rails application just to deploy one app instead of two on the clients server.

#### Example:

I have the rails application with administrational stuff and when the user visits something like `/coaching` the angular app should be served.

#### Now my questions are:

Do I put the angular app into the `/public` folder?
Do I have to add some sort of route or add the manifest to application.js or something like that? Or do I add a controller action that responds to "application.manifest"?

Thanks in advance, 
Jascha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed that easy, just putting the angular app in `/public` folder in a subfolder called `coaching` made the angular app accessible over `/coaching`.

Nothing to tweak in routes.rb or anything like that.